# Error when trying to connect to a Cloud SQL instance using the Cloud Shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-shell

I've had a Cloud SQL instance for about a year now.

I always accessed it the same way:

- I would go to my project on the Cloud Console.
- Click on the Cloud Shell icon at the top right (a small right pointing arrow).
- A black shell screen would pop up where I would type 
  `gcloud sql connect <my instance> --user=root`.
- Enter my password.

Now, all of a sudden, I am getting an error message saying:

> There was no instance found at projects//instances/ or you are not authorized to connect to it.

I am the owner of the project, and also have **Admin** rights to the Cloud SQL instance. The project and instance are still there, and my app that accesses the data stored in the instances' database is working fine - therefore I know the database is also present, otherwise my app wouldn't work.

I didn't touch or change anything in the Cloud SQL instance. Suddenly, I simply can't access my database using the exact same procedure I have been using almost every day over the past year now.

I am able to access the database using a local Python script on my laptop and the Cloud SQL Proxy, but I would like to access it from the Cloud Shell again.

Any ideas on what could the problem be?

Answer (score 4):

[gcloud components update](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/update) - update all of your installed components to the latest version

[gcloud init](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/init) - reinitialize gcloud shell. It performs the following setup steps:
Authorizes gcloud and other SDK tools to access Google Cloud Platform using your user account credentials, or from an account of your choosing whose credentials are already available.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there was a problem with the GCP Cloud Shell (even though there was no mention of it on the GCP error tracking page). When I logged back in today and followed the same above process everything worked well. 
Looks like GCP Cloud Shell could occasionally go rouge and start producing errors. Word of advice, don't panic when this happens (like I did) and start resetting, rebooting and messing up things. Just wait a day and check back again.